# Unbuffered misc_device read - linux kernel driver

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am writing a Linux misc_device driver and am having a problem with the read. Right now the kernel considers the driver as a fast device: the driver read are buffered until as much data as required by the user space caller is available (like when reading a file from the disk). This means that the read system call do not return until the buffer is full. I would like to change that behaviour and tell the kernel to return the system call as soon as some data are available (like a read on a socket).

Is it possible? How? Am I doing it completely wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't know if you are still interested in this question nine weeks later, but: are you sure that the blocking is happening in the kernel?  My recollection is that it is the driver's job to check O_NONBLOCK in the struct file f_flags and block waiting for input if necessary.  Otherwise, if O_NONBLOCK is not set it should read as much data as possible on each read call and return at once, and when a read call finally happens with no data left at all to read, return 0 bytes to tell the caller to stop.  Setting O_NONBLOCK or not is of course user space's job.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not answer my comment: normally any waiting until enough data is available is done by the driver (i.e. you have to do it in your code), not by generic kernel code, though your driver will use generic kernel code to do it[1].  You should check O_NONBLOCK in the struct file f_flags member to know whether you should wait or not.  However, user space may keep on calling read() in a loop until read() returns with zero bytes read.  So if you get a call to read and no new data has arrived since the last call, it is important to set bytes read to zero.  Hope that helps.

[1] http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-6-sect-2